# Execute Procedure when Value in a Cell/Range Changes

Tags: excel, vba, events

I'm new to VBA and wrote the following codes according to my data set. The goal here is to execute my procedure if a cell/range gets changed by pasting new data into the worksheet, most probably the sheet will be empty as it will follow by a clear content procedure. 
However, the code is not triggering the change event, I've tried several codes from Google, but none of them worked. Please note that my procedure gets me exactly the data I want in the format I want, however, if changes are needed, kindly let me know.

**PLEASE HELP**

**1. Change event trigger - stored under Sheet1**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call LoopandIfStatement
        Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

**2. My procedure - stored under Sheet1 below the event above**

```
Sub LoopandIfStatement()


Dim SHT As Worksheet

Set SHT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CB")

MyLr = SHT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim I As Long
For I = 1 To MyLr

Dim O As Long

Dim U As Range
Set U = SHT.Range("A" & I)

    If IsEmpty(SHT.Range("a" & I).Value) = False Then

        SHT.Range("k" & I).Value = SHT.Range("A" & I).Value

    Else

On Error GoTo ABC

        SHT.Range("k" & I).Value = U.Offset(-1, 0)

    End If

Next I

For O = 2 To MyLr

    If SHT.Range("g" & O).Value = "Closing Balance" Then

    SHT.Range("l" & O).Value = SHT.Range("j" & O).Value

      End If

  Next O

 ABC:

End Sub
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFAyV.png)

Comment: Your code will only run if the cell changed is in A1. That's what this line is doing: `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I see, thank you! I'm trying to figure out a code where it will trigger my procedure whenever I paste new data into the range A:J

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will trigger whenever new data is pasted in any cell of columns A to J

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:J")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Call LoopandIfStatement

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Regarding your sub LoopandIfStatement here are some suggestions:

1. Use `Option explicit` at the top of your modules (see [this](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html))
2. Declare all your variables (you're missing: `Dim MyLr as long`)
3. Try to name your variables to something understandable (e.g. instead of `MyLr` you could have `lastRow`)
4. If you need to exit a Sub you can use `Exit Sub` instead of a `Goto ABC`

---

**EDIT:**

Added code for the loop and the change worksheet event.

Paste it behind the `CB` Sheet module

Some highlights:

1. When you triggered the loop on each worksheet change, it would re-apply all the steps to all the cells. You can work with changed ranges using the `Target` argument/variable in the `Worksheet_Change` event
2. To loop through an existing range see the `AddAccountBalanceToRange` procedure
3. Try to think and plan your code in steps or actions that can be grouped
4. Use comments to describe the purpose of what you're doing
5. Remember to delete obsolete code (saw you had a copy of the procedure in a module)

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Columns("A:J").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CB").Range("A:J").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CB").Range("A:L").ClearContents
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim targetUsedRange As Range

    ' Do something on non empty cells
    Set targetUsedRange = Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.UsedRange)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:J")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Call AddAccountBalance(targetUsedRange)

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub AddAccountBalance(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim evalRow As Range

    Dim lastColumn As Long

    Dim accountNumber As String
    Dim balanceString As String
    Dim narrative As String
    Dim balanceValue As Long

    balanceString = "Closing Balance"

    ' If deleting or clearing columns
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Do something if there are any values in range
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    ' Get the parent sheet of the cells that were modifid
    Set targetSheet = Target.Parent

    ' Get the last empty cell column in row 1 -Cells(3 -> this is row 3)- In the sample book: column K
    lastColumn = targetSheet.Cells(3, targetSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Loop through each of the rows that were modified in range
    For Each evalRow In Target.Cells.Rows


        ' Do something if account number or narrative are not null
        If targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, 1).Value <> vbNullString Or targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, 7).Value <> vbNullString Then

            ' Store columns values in evaluated row
            accountNumber = targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, 1).Value
            narrative = targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, 7).Value
            If IsNumeric(targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, 10).Value) Then balanceValue = targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, 10).Value

            ' Add account number
            If accountNumber <> vbNullString Then
                targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, lastColumn).Value = accountNumber
            End If

            ' Add closing balance
            If narrative = balanceString Then
                targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, lastColumn).Value = targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, 1).Offset(-1, 0).Value
                targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, lastColumn).Offset(0, 1).Value = balanceValue
            End If

            ' Format last two columns (see how the resize property takes a single cell and expands the range)
            With targetSheet.Cells(evalRow.Row, lastColumn).Resize(, 2).Interior
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

            ' Auto fit last column (K) (you could use the resize property as in the previous statement)
            targetSheet.Columns(lastColumn).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End If

    Next evalRow

End Sub

Public Sub AddAccountBalanceToRange()

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim evalRange As Range


    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CB")
    Set evalRange = targetSheet.Range("A1:A42")

    AddAccountBalance evalRange

End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! this apprecaite your feedback so much.
regarding number 4, I found the following code on Google. Is this correct? and what's the difference between it and Goto ABC - End Sub ?


`On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

ErrorHandler:
Exit Sub`

Comment: Maybe you don’t need the error handler or maybe you do. I think it’s better to consider which cases would raise the errors and handle them accordingly, otherwise you may be bypassing errors that would return inconsistent information. If you want, here or in another question, ask/tell me what’s that code propose and I can take a look at it and improve it. If it’s in a new question, drop the link here

Comment: I'm getting the error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error on the following code. Given the data I have to work with, I need an offset. I have a sample file that I can share with you, showing the data layout that I will be dealing with on regular basis. This is my first actual loop, and I'm sure there are a lot of things to learn in order to be more efficient, so any help will be greatly appreciated. THANKS!
`SHT.Range("k" & I).Value = U.Offset(-1, 0)`

Comment: Please post the file link

Comment: Hi Ricardo, please let me know if the link below works.
I added few notes inside the document.

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vDEV816grJ2VtbBKvrpSOgwAAUQ4nrAF]

Comment: THANK YOU RICARDO! I'm still going over the code, trying to fully understand it.
However, I noticed that after running the procedure, everything takes places in Column J and K, deleting the Balance from column J from the original extract.
The data source runs from A:J, therefore the account number should start from K:L in this case. Is this due to the LastColumn code?

Comment: LastColumn code is like if you select the last cell in row 3 and press ctrl + left. I tested the code with the file you posted

Comment: hi Ricardo, I've been going the code and I've learnt a lot from your logic. I'm still not able to fix the problem! I included a screenshot of the results I get, at the end of the original post, under Results. Basically, the logic should be applied starting from Column K (last row +1) and onward. However, its being applied on column J as per my photo above, deleting the original column J, which contains all the balances. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Hi Musa, you can add 1 to the lastcolumn `lastColumn = targetSheet.Cells(3, targetSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1`

Comment: Thank you once more Ricardo! That worked like magic! I was trying to create an offset by adding a row to the lastrow

Comment: Yeap. in this case was just the column. Glad it helped

Comment: One final thing (hopefully) the balance is being copied as a whole number, without any decimal places. I believe it has tondo with the Dim declaration, thoughts on the fix?!

Comment: Sure, just change Long for Double

Comment: Thank you Ricardo, everything has worked perfectly.
I decided to automate the SUMIF formulas on the main reconcialation tab, I came up with the code below, but can't figure out why, it returns a value of 0 with no errors. I was hoping if you could have a look at my post below
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905397/vba-sumif-based-on-variables?noredirect=1#comment105938549_59905397)